# Avoiding overhead in a 'const' declaration

Tags: c#

I have declared a **const** in this way:

```
const string DatabaseFilePath = 
String.Format(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\Data Files\");
```

I am worried that the first "string" and the second "String.Format", might be adding some overhead. If it is true, suggest a better way to write this.

Comment: I'm suprised that even compiles.

Comment: Your `String.Format` call is useless and dangerous.

Comment: @SLaks: That's why I wanted to know. Thanks for your answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your declaration is a compiler error.
`const` fields must be *compile-time* constants; they *cannot* have method calls.

Instead, you need to make `static readonly` field.

Also, you should combine paths strings using [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx), which will correctly handle the `\`.

Change it to

```
static readonly string DatabaseFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Data Files\");
```

Comment: Oh. I was just looking at the red lines.

Comment: If the second string is not a folder but a file, will it work?

Answer (score 6):

> I have declared a const in this way:

No you haven't. This won't even compile unless you use some other language (not C#).

You probably mean a readonly field:

```
private readonly string DatabaseFilePath = 
    Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Data Files");
```

Also notice the usage of [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) instead of string.Format.

Comment: +1, Technically the OP can declare it this way, it just won't compile ;)

Comment: Removing the trailing \ may be a breaking change.

Comment: @SLaks, yes absolutely if you use string.Format. That's why `Path.Combine` is preferred. To add a file once again `Path.Combine` should be used.

Comment: What? That has nothing to do with `String.Format`. I'm talking about the end of the path.

Comment: I suppose that the final goal is to construct a filename. So if you do `DatabaseFilePath + "foo.txt"` then yes, removing the trailing slash is a breaking change, but if you do `Path.Combine(DatabaseFilePath, "foo.txt")`, with or without the trailing slash you will get a correct final path. And if the final goal is to simply use a path (without a filename) the trailing slash has not much effect.

Comment: @Darin: Yes. _If_ he changes all uses of the field to use `Path.Combine`, nothing will break.  If he misses one, he's in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

> I have declared a const in this way:

```
const string DatabaseFilePath = 
String.Format(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\Data Files\");
```

That will not compile, so you haven't. It won't compile because the expression is not constant. You might know that the result of that expression is constant (i.e., it is the same no matter how many times you call `String.Format` and `System.Windows.Form.Application.StartupPath` but the compiler doesn't know that! Additionally, there is no chance that `StartupPath` is constant since its value is runtime dependent.) You are asking too much for the compiler to be able to deduce that in cases where the expression actually is a constant.

> I am worried that the first "string" and the second "String.Format", might be adding some overhead.

Let's suppose that it did compile. It could only compile if the compiler were somehow able to magically determine that the expression you are assigning to `DatabaseFilePath` is constant. But if it can do that, then `DatabaseFilePath`'s value has been resolved at compile time. Therefore, the only overhead would be at compile time. There would not be any at runtime.

If this is the design that you want, you should declare it like so

```
static readonly string DatabaseFilePath =
Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Data Files");
```

but you should go one step beyond that and say

```
class X {
    private readonly string databaseFilePath;
    public X(string databaseFilePath) {
        this.databaseFilePath = databaseFilePath;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else

```
X x = new X(
    Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Data Files")
);
```

I don't know the name of your class, and I have elided the irrelevant details but the point is clear.